# Magento 2: Add custom value to $parent in checkout summary

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs, plugin

I want to add a custom value to the items in the order summary during checkout (`$parent`).
I followed all the other howtos on how to do it:

Create plugin for `Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider`:

etc/di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider">
        <plugin name="my_config_provider" type="My\Module\Plugin\ConfigProviderPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

This is my plugin:

```
namespace My\Module\Plugin;

class ConfigProviderPlugin extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject
     * @param array $result
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterGetConfig(\Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject, array $result): array
    {
        foreach ($result['quoteItemData'] as $key => $item) {
            $result['quoteItemData'][$key]['display_price'] = $item['row_total'];
            $result['quoteItemData'][$key]['display_price'] += $item['tax_amount'];
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

This is a simplyfied version of my plugin. I made sure this is properly implemented. The plugin is being called.

But it seems, that none of the modifications I make to `$result['quoteItemData']` make it to the frontend. The new `display_price` value is supposed to show up in `vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\summary\item\details.html` (but it does not).

```
<span class="qty-price" data-bind="text: getFormattedPrice($parent.display_price)"></span>
```

Also when I add a debug to the template it shows that $parent is unchanged:

```
<pre data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS($parent), null, 2)"></pre>
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Thank you

**EDIT:**

The weird part is that **NOTHING** I do to `quoteItemData` is being reflected in the frontend.

Just for exploring purposes I modified the core file `vendor\magento\module-checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider.php`. I added an extra entry to that array in `getQuoteItemData`. It does not get to the frontend whatsoever.